# install gulp's plugin using npm

Tags: npm, gulp, workflow, frontend

I'm confused using npm and gulp. I know gulp is merely a task runner , used to automate workflow and npm is basically node.js package manager.

But, to install a gulp plugin we run  `npm install --save-dev gulp-uglify`, why?

We install npm modules like passport using the same cli command : `npm install passport --save`.

How do I know which module is for gulp?

Answer (score 1):

npm is a package manager used for a wide range of needs and purposes.  gulp is simply one package of many that can be installed and gulp also relies on npm to install gulp plugins.

As such, you can't tell if a module is a gulp plugin except by naming convention.  This is why so many modules use names like `gulp-<something>` or `grunt-<whatever>` or even `<something>-generator`.  The customary part of the name helps clarify that the module is meant to be used to support another module (gulp, grunt, yeoman, webpack, and so on...).

So, you can't easily tell if a module is used as a gulp plugin unless the module author was helpful and put `gulp-` in the name or some other similar human-friendly text.

Comment: this is awful, if I made a gulp plugin and the naming doesn't have gulp as prefix then it cause a big problem.

Comment: There may be a misunderstanding.  You can create a gulp plugin and not use a gulp- prefix.  The prefix is there just to make it easier to tell what's used by gulp and what may be for other purposes.  The naming is for humans, not for gulp.